# How to set ggplot2 font family

Tags: r, unicode, fonts, ggplot2

I use R/RStudio on osx. The font family must to be set in the images that contains the unicode character. 
e.g. `plot(1:10, 1:10, main="中文", sub="中文", family="宋体")`

How to set `family="宋体"` in ggplot?

The ggplot function I used:

```
ggplot(subset(v, s>15157000), aes(x=V2, y=V5, group=V1,color=as.character(V1))) + 
    geom_line()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument `base_family` in `theme_grey()` should help; then see this for a discussion about Chinese fonts: http://cos.name/cn/topic/101521